# Excel VBA-Find string in sheet2 and copy the this in sheet1

Tags: string, excel, vba, copy, paste

i look for a Code in VBA to look after Strings (called "Setup") in sheet2 and copy the String under "Setup" into sheet1 in cell A1.

I have a not working code from a recorded macro:

```
Sub FindString()

Cells.Find(What:="Setup", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
    :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

Range("I8").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Tabelle1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

If i change that String, it Shows me error 91...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub FindString()
Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
Cells.Find(What:="Setup", LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
    :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

ActiveCell.Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
' Specify the string to find in sheet1 B1 cell
Sub FindString2()
Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
Cells.Find(What:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Value, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
    :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

ActiveCell.Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you the first part is effective, but if there are more than one strings with the same Name, and i want the second one if ist possible to take that second?

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Punith's answer, except you don't need to change sheets.

```
Option Explicit
Sub find_string()
    Const strLookup As String = "Setup"
    Dim wb As Workbook, find_ws As Worksheet, to_ws As Worksheet, rngFound As Range

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set find_ws = wb.Sheets("find")
    Set to_ws = wb.Sheets("to")

    Set rngFound = find_ws.Cells.Find(What:=strLookup, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Offset(1, 0)
    to_ws.Range("A1").Value = rngFound.Value
End Sub
```